# binary search:please tell me whats wrong here

Tags: error-handling, binary-tree

I tried binary tree data structure but found it to be not working and giving an error. Please correct my code. Thanks!

It gives warning but with the inputs in `main` it stops running .

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    int item;
    struct node * leftc;
    struct node * rightc;
}node;

void create(int key, node **tree )
{
    if(*tree ==0)
    {
        (*tree)= (node *)malloc(sizeof(node *));
        (*tree)->item=key;
        (*tree)->leftc=((*tree)->rightc)=NULL;
    } 
    else
{
    if(key >= (*tree)->item )
    {
        create(key, &((*tree)->rightc));
    }
    else if(key<(*tree)->item)
    {
        create(key, &((*tree)->leftc));
    }
}
}

node * search(int key, node * tree)
{
    if(tree !=NULL)
    {
      if(key == tree->item)
        return tree;
      else if(key > tree->item)
        search(key, tree->rightc);
      else
        search(key, tree->leftc);
    }
  return NULL;
}

void cut(node * tree)
{
  if(tree != NULL)
  {
    cut(tree->leftc);
    cut(tree->rightc);
    free(tree);
  }
}

void print_preorder(node * tree)
{
if (tree) {
 printf("%d\n",tree->item);
 print_preorder(tree->leftc);
 print_preorder(tree->rightc);
}
}


int main()
{
   node * root=NULL;
 create(9,&root);
 create(16,&root);
 create(24,&root);
 create(6,&root);

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: i know its a tedious task to read the full code.but you may compile and see if you can get anything from warnings your compiler gives

Comment: What is the error it is giving you?

Comment: expected 'struct node *' but argument is of type 'struct node *' is the warning

Comment: That's the warning, but what is the error?

Comment: program just crashes.

Comment: Works for me... Are you sure you're just expecting something to be printed when you don't actually ask it to print anything? Try adding `print_preorder(root);` after `create(6,&root);` and see if it prints anything.

Comment: @jonhopkins ,no sir i am not expecting it to print anything. i just want to use create function.

Comment: @jonhopkins check for these calls  create(9,&root);
    create(5,&root);
create(24,&root);

Comment: What makes you say that it is crashing? Is the console not doing anything at all, not even returning to the usable prompt? Is it telling you that there is a segmentation fault or something? Please be specific, because after copying and pasting your code and running it, it works exactly as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
typedef struct
{
    int item;
    struct node * leftc;
    struct node * rightc;
}node;
```

to

```
typedef struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node * leftc;
    struct node * rightc;
}node;
```

Within your structure you refer to 'struct node' so you need the name in order for it to properly reference itself. Of course, after the typedef then you can just refer to it as node.

The test program compiled and ran fine with the code given otherwise.

Comment: Very nice. Can't believe I missed that, but that gets rid of all the warnings OP mentioned.

Comment: @jonhopkins GCC gives a "Invalid use of incomplete type 'struct node' error" and a "forward declaration of 'struct node'" error. So it did the heavy lifting :)
Hoder: Good. You're welcome. For future reference read the FAQ when you want to ask questions. Asking duplicate questions is frowned upon here. Good luck with your tree implementation.

Comment: I was only getting warnings like `test.c: In function ‘create’:
test.c:22:9: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
test.c:10:6: note: expected ‘struct node **’ but argument is of type ‘struct node **’
test.c:26:9: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
test.c:10:6: note: expected ‘struct node **’ but argument is of type ‘struct node **’`, nothing like what you got.

Comment: @jonhopkins Haha my bad. That is actually because I compiled it as C++ using G++ rather than C with GCC. Changing the file to a C file and compiling with GCC gives me what you got. Looks like the C++ error output is much better than C in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question about the error, but I noticed a major problem with your `search()` function. You only return the node you're looking for if it's the first one that is put into the function. The recursive calls to `search()` do not return anything. The function should look something like this:

```
node * search(int key, node * tree)
{
    if (tree !=NULL)
    {
        if (key == tree->item) {
            return tree;
        } else if (key > tree->item) {
            return search(key, tree->rightc);
        } else if (key < tree->item) {
            return search(key, tree->leftc);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Also, in your `create()` function, did you mean to check `if (*tree == NULL)` instead of `if (*tree == 0)`?

Comment: ,thanks for your time and effort. it was a silly mistake by me corrected by Dean.